# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I'm new to programming, could you please help me with this one:

I'am getting an error in "To.List()"
    Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type    'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

My Code is:

```
List<IncByYrMonthModel> GroupedList = (from p in incidentsViewModel
                                       group p by new 
                                       { 
                                           month = p.DateClosed.Value.Month, 
                                           year = p.DateClosed.Value.Year 
                                       } into d
                                       select new 
                                       {
                                           d.Key.month, 
                                           d.Key.year, 
                                           count = d.Count() 
                                        }).ToList();
return GroupedList;
```

My Model is:

```
public class IncByYrMonthModel
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
}
```

Updated code

```
public List<IncByYrMonthModel> GetYrMonth2(HttpSessionStateBase session, int id, int _StrYear)
{
    List<IncidentsModel> incidentsViewModel = ViewModelService.Fetch<List<IncidentsModel>>(session, id);

    List<IncByYrMonthModel> GroupedList = (from p in incidentsViewModel
                                           group p by new 
                                           { 
                                               month = p.DateClosed.Value.Month, 
                                               year = p.DateClosed.Value.Year 
                                            } into d
                                            select new IncByYrMonthModel 
                                            { 
                                                Month = d.Key.month, 
                                                Year = d.Key.year, 
                                                Total = d.Count() 
                                            });

        return GroupedList;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just change this

```
select new { d.Key.month, d.Key.year, count = d.Count() }
```

to this

```
select new IncByYrMonthModel { Month = d.Key.month, Year = d.Key.year, Total = d.Count() }
```

The problem in the first case is that you have a sequence of object of an anonymous type, which you try to convert them to a list of `IncByYrMonthModel`, which is impossible.

Comment: Error: The type or namespace name 'IncByYrMonthModel' could not be found

Comment: @gareching then include it. Just right click on it and the resolve references.

Comment: I just have one concern, I think I need to change year, month and total to Int as I encountered an error "Cannot implicitly convert  type 'string' to int,

Comment: @gareching sure thing, this is the correct one. I didn't even notice their types :)

Comment: Question: I haven't run this code yet, but I wanted to make the month in string like "January", "February" Etc.

Comment: Then you could leave the month to be a string and in the projection jsut make a minor change: `Month = d.Key.monthToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))`. Don't  forget to include the `using System.Globalization;` at the corresponding section of your source code file.

Comment: after resolving int issues: encountered another error with the code you have provided:

Comment: Then probably the problem relies on another part of your code. Certainly, it has to do with the signature of the method, in which you have declared this query. I bet that the type that returns is `IEnumerable<TG.Dashboard.ServiceBus.IncidentsByYrMonthMode>` and not `List<TG.Dashboard.ServiceBus.IncidentsByYrMonthMode>`. The solution is quite straightforward, either change the return type or the type of `GroupedList`. I would remove only the `ToList`. In other words I would have picked the second option.

Comment: @gareching Then please post your whole code (I mean the method's code). Otherwise, we can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: Ok it's clear. If you use the `ToList` it will works. Otherwise change the return type to IEnumerable<IncByYrMonthModel>.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically trying to assign an anonymous type

> new { d.Key.month, d.Key.year, count = d.Count() }

to your object. Instead of select new { ... }, just select new IncByYrMonthModel() { ... } to populate your object.